# div with bootstrap class "d-sm-none" is displayed on every screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have written this markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
<a class="navbar-brand overflow-hidden pr-3" href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">
    <!--<img src="~/Content/Theme/images/logo-dark.png" alt="" />-->
    <img src="~/Content/Theme/images/Velosi/applusLogo.jpg" style="height:50px" alt="" />
</a>

<div class="d-sm-none">
    <h3>THIS SHOULD BE ONLY DISPLAYED ON MOBILE PHONES</h3>
</div>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <div class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic">
        <div class="hamburger-box">
            <div class="hamburger-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
```

I expect the

```
<div class="d-sm-none">
    <h3>THIS SHOULD BE ONLY DISPLAYED ON MOBILE PHONES</h3>
</div>
```

to be only displayed on cell phones and not beyond, but it is displayed on every screen size. Why is that?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that bootstrap isn't loaded, or that something is preventing it from running properly. Please create a [MCVE] (complete html including head and body) and check your console for any errors and paste them here. Also tell us which devices and browser(s) your are using to test this, and disable any browser plugins/extensions to make sure it's not caused by interference of some third party tool.

Comment: This is not reproducible

Answer (score 1):

try this：

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block">
```